# Is it possible to pass data from MKAnnotation without using a segue and just presenting a View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, mkannotationview, presentviewcontroller

For some strange reason, `Xcode` doesn't recognize my segue when I create it and use         `performSegueWithIdentifier("Details", sender: self)`.

[image]

But I was able to find a way around this by presenting the view controller with this:

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewController") as! UIViewController

self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I pass data from the `MKAnnotationView`, to the new details view if I'm not using a `segue`? (func `prepareForSegue` requires a segue to pass data right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// You have to make object of that `DetailViewController(Class Name)` rather than `viewController`

```
let viewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewController") as! DetailViewController
```

// Then you can access variable of `DetailsViewController` Like This:

`viewController.parameter = whatever`

```
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

On your segue not recognized issue -

Show/push segues have to be performed by a navigation controller.

Like Dhaval said, you don't have to use segues to pass data though. All you need is a public property/public method that you can use to pass the data.